# Button title goes behind gradient layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know the fact that if we add the title after assigning the gradient to the button as sublayer, button's title will be in front.

But this case is different.

I am changing gradient for normal state and touched down states of button.

Here is my code :

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{

    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    // Finding old gradient layer to remove it
    for (CALayer *layer in [sender.layer.sublayers copy]){
        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:@"gradientLayer"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }


    // Applying the new gradient
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:0.81 blue:0.00 alpha:0.95]; // Original
    UIColor *colorThree = [[UIColor brownColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    UIColor *colorFour = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = sender.layer.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5].CGColor,(id) colorTwo.CGColor,(id) colorThree.CGColor,(id) colorFour.CGColor, nil];
    gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
    sender.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = sender.layer.cornerRadius;

    // Adding gradient
    [sender.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    gradientLayer.name = @"gradientLayer";

    // Adding title after applying the gradient ( BUT ALSO TITLE IS GOING BEHIND THE GRADIENT )
    sender.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    sender.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    NSString *str = sender.titleLabel.text;
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
-(void) touchedDown:(UIButton*)sender{

    // Finding old gradient layer to remove it
    for (CALayer *layer in [sender.layer.sublayers copy]){
        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:@"gradientLayer"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }

    // Applying the new gradient
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer1.frame = sender.layer.bounds;
    gradientLayer1.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f].CGColor, nil];
    gradientLayer1.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
    gradientLayer1.cornerRadius = sender.layer.cornerRadius;

    // Adding Gradient
    [sender.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer1];
    gradientLayer1.name = @"gradientLayer";
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

At first time when i launch the app, title is at front. But when i start clicking it, then the title goes behind the gradient. Kindly help me with this problem. Thanks for the time (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[sender.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

That means: add the gradient layer *in front of all other sublayers*. That includes the layer that displays the title label.

Instead, call `insertSublayer:atIndex:` (or `above:` or `below:`) to position the layer among the other layers where you want it.

However, it would be even better not to mess with the button's layers directly at all. Instead of applying the gradient as a layer, draw the gradient (in code) into an image and use that image as the button's background image.

Moreover, you can configure the background image to change *automatically* when the user is tapping the button.

Comment: How do i find the index ?

Comment: OMG Man.. Worked like a charm. Thanks for the information about `insertSublayer:atIndex`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help, but it sounds like you are still setting the layer instead of the background image. You really shouldn't be doing that! :)